# ZxingのQRコード作成をJava1.5で行う方法を教えてください。

Tags: java, qr-code

ZxingのQRコード作成をJava1.5で行おうとしています。

ですが、javase と core のjar のどれをダウンロードしても、
Javaプログラムの実行時に、下記のバージョン違い？エラーになり例外が発生します。

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Bad version number in .class file (unable to load class com.google.zxing.WriterException)
```

※Javaが古いのは承知していますが、既に数年稼働しているLinuxサーバーのプログラムは、
Java 1.5で開発・ビルドされている為、このバージョンのままで、Zxing を使いたいです。

ダウンロードして試したZxingのjarのバージョンは以下の通りです。

javase-1.7.jar     core-1.7.jar
javase-2.0.jar     core-...
javase-2.1.jar     core-...
javase-2.2.jar     core-...
javase-2.3.0.jar   core-...
javase-3.0.0.jar   core-...
javase-3.0.1.jar   core-...
javase-3.1.0.jar   core-...
javase-3.2.0.jar   core-...
javase-3.2.1.jar   core-...
javase-3.3.0.jar   core-...

他に、Java 1.5で使用可能なjarはありますか？（ダウンロード先が無いか探しましたが見つかっていません。）
もしくは、どのような対応をすれば、Java 1.5 で、Zxing で QRコードを作成できますか？

ちなみに、プログラムは下記のように記述しています。

```
    public String make_QR_code_file(String strPara_QR_code, int iPara_size)
    {
        try {
            String contents = strPara_QR_code;              // QRコード化する文字列
            BarcodeFormat format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;   // QRコード形式を指定

            int width  = iPara_size;                        // QRコードの横サイズ
            int height = iPara_size;                        // QRコードの縦サイズ

            // 異なる型の値を入れるためgenericは使えない
            Hashtable<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel> hints = new Hashtable<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel>();

            // 日本語を扱うためにシフトJISを指定
//          hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8");

            //エラー修復レベルを指定
            // ErrorCorrectionLevel.L : 7%の補正レベル
            // ErrorCorrectionLevel.M : 15%の補正レベル
            // ErrorCorrectionLevel.Q : 25%の補正レベル
            // ErrorCorrectionLevel.H : 30%の補正レベル
            hints.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.M);

            //QRコードをエンコードするクラス
            QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();

            BitMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode(contents, format, width, height, hints);
            BufferedImage image = MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(bitMatrix);
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("/usr/local/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/webapps/ROOT/api/file/qr_code_0001/barcode.png"));

// とりあえずの戻り値
            return "";
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

このExceptionが出力されるのは、実行環境より上位バージョンのJavaでコンパイルされているのが原因です。

```
『org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Bad version number in .class file (unable to load class com.google.zxing.WriterException)』
```

そのようなライブラリを下位バージョンのJavaで利用したい場合、そのバージョンでコンパイルするのが解決策になります。

ただし、`ZXing`は(Githubを見る限り)2.3.0の時点でJava7でコンパイルする前提になっているようなので、Java5でコンパイルが通る可能性は低いと思います。
残念ですが、`ZXing`を利用するのであれば、Java環境を7以上にする必要があると思います。

Comment: そうでしたか、情報ありがとうございます。大変たすかりました。他のライブラリをさがして、試してみます。できれば、よく使われていて、Googleさんが提供しているのでこれを使いたかったのですが、しかたないですね。お手数をお掛け致しました。ありがとうございました。